# Alert if a prometheus gauge metric is reported for more than 3 hours

Tags: prometheus, metrics, promql

I have a process running on every host in the infrastructure once every month or so. Whenever the process is running on any host, it  sends a metric "process_running{instance=<>}" once every minute and when process exits, obviously no metric is sent to prom from that host. Now I want to alert whenever the process is stuck on any host - that is running for > 3h. I tried various combinations of absent() and metric<> itself. But it does not work when i do group by (instance)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the interval between samples for the metric `process_running`, which as recorded by Prometheus for the given `instance` (this interval is known as `scrape_interval`), then the following query can be used for determining time series, which last for more than 3 hours during the last day:

```
(count_over_time(process_running[1d]) * scrape_interval) > 3*3600
```

If the `scrape_interval` is unknown, then Prometheus doesn't provide the ability for determining time series duration. In this case you can use [lifetime()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#lifetime) function from VictoriaMetrics (this is a Prometheus-like monitoring system I work on). For example, the following [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) query returns time series, which were receiving samples for more than 3 hours during the last day:

```
lifetime(process_running[1d]) > 3h
```